# Download file as pdf from Google Drive

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I have to download all Google drive files.  i am trying to follow this 
[for Getting download url](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples) and using this code for pdf url
i am getting downloadurl using

```
file.getDownloadUrl()
```

but when i am calling for download or converting into stream it is throwing error 404: not found.

where i am missing .. some authentication issue or some thing beyond .....
for downloading i am using like this ...

```
InputStream tempstream = Temp.downloadFile(service, file);
```

and

```
private static InputStream downloadFile(Drive service, File file) {
if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
  try {
      //download url is  : "https://doc-0s-9k-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/6rpci9p5rgc1ards1udmrkv5oparm1a2/eoas3kt0uj6afg559kiugg3d6fftlere/1357740000000/06400000604443042302/18001816663358798513/0B2tdn0tkhMowTFVyRzYzaGhWeTQ?h=16653014193614665626&e=download&gd=true" 
    HttpResponse resp =
        service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
            .execute();
    return resp.getContent();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // An error occurred.
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
} else {
  // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
  return null;
}
```

}

downloadurl 
please help... i feel some i am not able to call method with proper authentication....

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure:

1. Your service is authorized
2. Your download URL is fresh (because they expire)

Otherwise your code is correct. For more info:

https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads

Comment: Thanks ! i am able to get Inputstream as content but it is not generating required file..when i am writing to some output stream .. how i can assure input stream is coming correct or not ??