# parse with php a pdf file archived on google drive

Tags: php, pdf, google-drive-api

I try to retrieve data from a PDF file stored on Google Drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2WQL_qJBr5UaDFoaTY2UTJwV3M/edit
I already parsed html files xith php, but here I can not directly obtain the html code for that file, it is encapsulated in a google api.
How can I easily this code to parse the content and recover my data?

Comment: Another example why that "everything into the cloud" strategy is very questionable. Look at your situation: it is _your_ file and you cannot access it the way you want. Great.

Answer (score 1):

First you need is the API to access the file - 
Check https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-downloads

Easy way is to download that file using google apis and then you can do what ever you want.

Comment: I tried : https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2WQL_qJBr5UaDFoaTY2UTJwV3M&q="fullText contains 'Trado'" but nothing.can you explain me the syntax ? –

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232487/download-file-as-pdf-from-google-drive

Comment: I do not have download rights. is there a different method ?
probably since I see the content in Chrome ?